# Batch File - Make a copy on network computer every 24 hours (only updated or new files)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, robocopy

I want to use Task Schedule to make a backup of a directory from one shared folder from COMPUTER-A to a shared folder on the network on COMPUTER-2.

To do this, I was thinking of using a batch file then using task scheduler to run the batch file every 24 hours.

I want it initially to make a copy of all the files from COMPUTER-A/SharedFolder to COMPUTER-B/SharedFolder - once this is done, the next time it runs I would like it to only update the files of those which have been modified or new system files.

I am using ROBOCOPY to do this at the moment and this is the code I have:-

```
ROBOCOPY "\\COMPUTER-A\SharedFolder" "\\COMPUTER-B\SharedFolder" *.* /Z /MOT:10080
```

This is only updating new files every 7 days and seems to be making duplications of files and folders.

If anybody could help me with this, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This should mirror the folder, with subdirectories, to the target, and then only copy new/changed files while removing deleted files.

```
ROBOCOPY "\\COMPUTER-A\SharedFolder" "\\COMPUTER-B\SharedFolder" /mir /z
```